# error on satellites after upgrade Gitlab from 5.4 to 6.0

Tags: git, gitlab

I upgraded Gitlab based on Gitlab's update manual
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/update/5.4-to-6.0.md
and worked without problems, after update executed the task

`sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production`

to verify problems and I get this message in many repositories

```
Try fixing it:
 sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:satellites:create RAILS_ENV=production
 If necessary, remove the tmp/repo_satellites directory ...
 ... and rerun the above command
 For more information see:
 doc/raketasks/maintenance.md 
 Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
```

I executed `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:satellites:create RAILS_ENV=production`
and `gitlab:check` still show the same error, and there's no tmp/repo_satellites directory

Comment: Does the git user has permission to create that directory?

Comment: yes, the satellites repository is in git user and git group. when was Gitlab 5.4 the task to create satellites worked

Comment: I found the problem, the Gitlab tasks are working. I increase the disk space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [issue 1788](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1788#issuecomment-9749935):

> Didn't realize that the satellite was going to take up so much disk space (seems to be a clone of the repo ++).

So much so that there are queries (like [issues/4388](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4388)) to request creating repos *without* satellite.

Yet, they are needed, full clone of the repos, and used to handle merge requests.